# dynamically load form in codeigniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter-2

I am new to codeigniter trying out some simple pages. I have successfully connected to the database for inserting and updating. But now I want to populate the fields from the database for updating. That is when the user selects the name from the dropdown the corresponding values should appear in the other fields so that the user can update easily.

I have worked on this to do without ajax or jquery. It worked for me but with some warning message - Use of undefined constant.

I am giving by mvc. Help me clear this.

Controller:

```
public function update()
{
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$data['title'] = 'Update Type';
$data['product_type'] = $this->editType_model->get_product_type();
    $data['row'] = $this->editType_model->get_row();

$this->form_validation->set_rules('productype', 'productype', 'required');

if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
{
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);   
    $this->load->view('cm/update', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
else
{
        $data['title']= 'Updation';
        $data['message']= 'Updation succeeded';
    $this->editType_model->update_news();
    $this->load->view('cm/success', $data);
}
}
```

Model:

```
public function get_product_type() {
    $data = array();
            $this->db->order_by("product_type_name", "desc"); 
    $query = $this->db->get('product_type');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
    }   
    $query->free_result();
    return $data;   
}
public function get_row() {
    $data = array();
                $id= $_POST[product_type_id];
    $query = $this->db->get_where('product_type', array('product_type_id' => $id));
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
    }   
    $query->free_result();
            return $data;   

}
public function update_news()
{
$this->load->helper('date');
$Product = $this->input->post('product_type_id');
$data = array(
    'product_type_name'=>($_POST['productype']),
    'rank'=>($_POST['rank'])        
            );
$this->db->where('product_type_id',$Product);
return $this->db->update('product_type', $data);
}
```

View:

```
<?php $productType = 0;
if(isset($_POST['product_type_id'])){
$productType = $_POST['product_type_id'];
}?>
<div id="Content"><div>
<form action="" method="post" name="f1">
<table ><tr><td>Select Product Type Name:</td>
    <td><Select id="product_type_id" name="product_type_id" onChange="document.f1.submit()">
            <option value="0">--SELECT</option>
            <?php if (count($product_type)) {
                              foreach ($product_type as $list) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $list['product_type_id']; ?>" 
            <?php if($productType==$list['product_type_id']) echo     "Selected" ?> >
            <?php echo $list['product_type_name'];  ?></option>
            <?php }} ?></Select></td></tr></table></form>
<?php   if($productType){
            if (count($row)) {
        foreach ($row as $faProductType) { ?>
    <div > <form action="" method="post" class="form-Fields" >
    <input type="hidden" name="product_type_id" id="product_type_id" value="<?php echo     $faProductType['product_type_id']; ?>" >
    <table border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" >
    <tr><td>Product Type <font color="red">*</font></td><td style="width: 10px;"> :         </td>
     <td><input name="productype" type="text" value="<?php echo     $faProductType['product_type_name']; ?>" style=" width:300px;" /></td>
            <td><span class="err" id="productTypeDesc1Err"></span></td></tr>
         <tr><td >Rank</td><td style="width:10px;"> : </td>
            <td ><input type="text" name="rank" id="rank" value="<?php echo     $faProductType['rank']; ?>" size="39" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="err"     id="productTypeNameErr"></span></td>
            <td ></td></tr><tr><td></td><Td colspan="2" align="center">
            <input type="submit" value="Update" class="buttonimg"      name='cm/editType/update' style="width:100px"
            onClick="return validEditProductType();">
            </Td><td></td></tr></table></form></div></div></div>
<?php }}} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Ajax for this purpose
onchange of your select box fill a div with form.

Controller Method

```
function getUserdata(){
    $where['username'] = $this->input->post('username');
    $this->load->model('users_model');
    $data['user'] = $this->users_model->getUser($where);
    $this->load->view('userform',$data);
}
```

And you model method

```
function getUser($where){
    return $this->db->where($where)->get('usertable')->row()
}
```

Ajax

```
$(function(){
    $('#selecttion').change(function(){
         var username = $(this).val();
         $.ajax({
            url : '<?php 'echo url to controller method'?>',
            type : 'POST'  ,
            data : 'username='+username,
            success : function(data){
                $('#dividtofill').html(data);
            }
         }); 

    });
})
```

EDIT :

calling ajax is easy
for this include jquery library in your header.
Here is your dropdown

Note : put the above ajax code in your head section in script

```
<select name="user" id="selecttion">
    <option value="John">John</option>
    <option value="Sam">Sam</option>
    <option value="David">David</option>
</select>
```

Now when this dropdown value is changed the ajax function defined above will be called.

Comment: I could understand the logic behind this. but can u let me know how I have to call this ajax in my view.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally cleared the error. I have done this by a simple if isset loop.

Now my get_row() in my model looks like this.

```
public function get_row() {
            $data = array();
$id= 0;
if(isset($_POST['product_type_id'])){
$id = $_POST['product_type_id'];
}
$query = $this->db->get_where('product_type', array('product_type_id' => $id));
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
$data[] = $row;
}
}
    $query->free_result();
    return $data;   
}
```